# Android VideView Resizing Algorithm

Tags: android, video-processing, android-videoview, dynamic-resizing

Can someone point me to the source code/ or documentation of resizing code that Android VideoView uses to resize videos to fit the screen when videos of dimensions other than the screen resolution are attempted to be displayed?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? **videoView** is likely using the standard formula for [aspect ratio calculation](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=aspect+ratio+formula). For landscape mode fit: `Disp_Width = ( (input_width / input_height) * Disp_Height );` and swap around the width/height if it's portrait mode needed to fit. In that code example you need to know height/width of your _input_ video and also the screen's _display_ resolution in height then it can tell you what number to set as displayed width of video.

Comment: I am actually looking for the algorithm used for the rescaling operation - whether it is bilinear/bicubic or lanczos interpolations.